# Job offer doesn't include insurance costs

Tags: job-offer, united-states, insurance

I received a job offer. The salary is on the low end of my acceptable range, but I like everything else about the job, including an unexpected sign-on bonus.

My only concern is that they can't tell me what the costs are for the health insurance plans they offer. After asking multiple times, I've been told that they have an "insurance marketplace" with several different providers, so they can't tell me amounts for the premiums. They won't provide current or future premiums for any of the plans available, or even ranges.

They have provided information about the plans available, including annual out-of-pocket maximums and copayments/coinsurance. But that doesn't help me figure out how much I'll be paying each month for health insurance, and I know that monthly premiums can vary widely, from tens of dollars a month to several hundred. (This is in the US.)

I'd be less hesitant if the offered salary was higher, but as it is I'm not sure I'd accept the job if the insurance was going to cost me $500 a month. Should I decide on the offer with the assumption that I'll need to pay the same prices as the open marketplace, or are there other things I should be considering?

Comment: What was their reason for why they can't tell you the costs?

Comment: Offer is already lowball, now they stalling with insurance ... If you have something better simply pass this.

Comment: How large is the company? How old are you? What kind of job is this? What other benefits are they offering? Have you looked on glassdoor, or teamblind? May be try asking how much the employer is contributing, if anything, to the share of the cost per month. For now, assume that they're not contributing anything (since their salary is on the low end and since they don't want to divulge a range of what you'll be paying).

Comment: A location would help. If this is US, I'd imagine they're going to steer you to your state's insurance exchange, and you will pay out-of-pocket for the total amount.  Be careful about just adding that amount to your asking salary, as insurance rates are rising quite quickly.

Comment: Regarding the close vote: Although your question is worded like you're asking our advice on a choice ("Should I do X or Y"), I think what you're actually asking is, "Is my assumption about what I might have to pay reasonable". Is that correct?

Comment: Obviously they can't tell you the future costs, but they should be able to pass on the current cost.  Are they refusing to do that?  Normally there's a summary sheet that lists plan options and cost.

Comment: @sf02 I added some info to explain their justification for not telling the cost. I don't think the explanations are reasonable, but it's what they gave me.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I'm in my 30s, it's a large company, the other benefits (vacation, 401k match) are comparable to other jobs I've looked at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with the comments saying that, as you say, this is already on the low-end of your expectation, *and* you will definitely have to cover your own insurance.

I suggest you do a thorough research and find exactly (or a more confident interval) what will the insurance cost you, compare your numbers and decide among the other offers you have. In the end the choice is yours and should be taken according to your needs and expectations. Don't settle for something you are not comfortable with.

Also, if this is already low-end, I strongly suggest you consider other options that are offering you better payment and, ideally, also cover insurance.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if they are unwillingly to tell you about your insurance costs, I think it's best to assume a worst-case scenario and evaluate the offer on the basis of that. You could also try to use this lack of (essential) financial information on the whole compensation package to negotiate a higher salary.

Answer (score 4):

> After asking multiple times, I've been told that they have an "insurance marketplace" with several different providers, so they can't tell me amounts for the premiums. They won't provide current or future premiums for any of the plans available, or even ranges.

Seems like this is one of these situations:

- The company is lazy and doesn't want to compile the insurance information to you.
- The company is trying to hide this information from you until after you have agreed to join the company
- The company doesn't actually provide any insurance plans for their employees so they can't give you this information.

None of these look like a company worth working for.  Add the fact that the offered salary is at the low end of your range, you may want to re-consider their offer.

Answer (score 2):

Every company who provides healthcare coverage to its employees knows exactly what it will cost the employee.  The costs are built in to the selection process, how else would you choose?  If "marketplace" means the US guaranteed insurance marketplace (healthcare.gov), then you will be paying the full cost, and it will be a lot.

This is a bad company with bad policies.

Comment: I think the employer is being honest about what they mean by insurance marketplace, that they have plans from several insurers available (who probably all also have different tiered plans), because I've had an employer that does the same thing and they use the same terminology. They *shouldn't* because it's confusing, but I don't think they mean the government's marketplace.

Answer (score -1):

> I'd be less hesitant if the offered salary was higher, but as it is I'm not sure I'd accept the job if the insurance was going to cost me $500 a month. Should I decide on the offer with the assumption that I'll need to pay the same prices as the open marketplace, or are there other things I should be considering?

Why couldn't you just ask the employer in this same exact fashion? "I'm wondering how much you'll take out each paycheck for these plans?" And see what they answer with?

My guess is they didn't understood your question. "How much I pay?" can mean your deductible, so their answer isn't secretive.

Comment: From the OP's post, I am sure the company understood the question. They have not arranged a group policy and so can't possibly answer the question. It's like asking my employer how much my motor insurance will be next year. They aren't arranging it and so can't know.